# Is there an API (SOAP, JSON, XML-RPC, REST, anything) to Google Code Issues?

Tags: google-code

Is there any programmatic way to read the data stored in a Google Code Project Hosting "Issues" tracker? Ideally it'd be nice to update/add issues too, but first I need some structured form of data from the tracker. I only see the HTML pages, and an Atom feed for issue updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there is one.

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/issue-tracker-data-api-for-project.html

Comment: Not anymore available: http://googleblog.blogspot.it/2012/12/winter-cleaning.html

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be but they have promised it's coming during the [Google Wave introduction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_UyVmITiYQ). The demo is at [minute 61](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_UyVmITiYQ#t=61m39) and your question is answered at [minute 78](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_UyVmITiYQ#t=78m23).