# Accessing a google code repository to get statistics

Tags: google-code, bitbucket

Code hosting sites such as github and bitbucket have public api's to retrieve statistics of project repositories. Is there such an api in google code or any other way to retrieve statistics about a google code project repository?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I found thus far is the Issue tracker api.
Got that from the question: [Is there an api soap json xml rpc rest anything to google code issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151641/is-there-an-api-soap-json-xml-rpc-rest-anything-to-google-code-issues)